# Iterate only once using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Funny thing, the following test works:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Iterate_Once()
    {
        var x = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.ToIterable();
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 1, 2 }, x.Take(2).ToArray());
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 3, 4, 5 }, x.Take(3).ToArray());
    }
```

Where:

```
static class Iterable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToIterable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var it = source.ToList().GetEnumerator();
        return once();

        IEnumerable<T> once()
        {
            while (it.MoveNext())
                yield return it.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

That should be safe to do not dispose an iterator of in-memory collection.

Please do not put me in jail for that :)

Comment: IMO this is more of a theoretical than a review question, but could you please explain your assertion "that should be safe to do not dispose of in-memory collection" - at least for me?

Comment: @HenrikHansen We use `List<T>` iterator here which is `IDisposable`. I bet that this concrete `Dispose()` implementation does nothing, so it should be safe to do not invoke it.

Comment: OK, betting is a strange kind of development paradigm and relying on an implementation detail is likewise probably not a good idea :-). BtW: the meaning of x.Take(3) (after calling x.Take(2)) is somewhat different than the normal behavior on this kind of IEnumerable<T> return by ToIterable(). Further will for instance `x.Take(3); x.Any(i => i == 1);` return false for `Any()`, and many other `IEnumerable<T>` linq-apis will behave unexpectedly on this kind of `IEnumerable<T>`. IMO you're mixing two distinct concepts that should be kept distinct.

Comment: Why would you do this and not just use ToArray or ToList?

Comment: @CharlesNRice Because i am getting here something like a “stream reader” semantics, which behaves differently from ToList or ToArray.

Comment: It's the same as saying ToList().AsEnumerable()  I'm not understanding what the root requirement is.

Comment: @CharlesNRice it is not :) try the code. We have a second degree function here, a functional programming trick - it requires some FP experience to see what is going on here :)

Comment: I see what you doing now. You want something like obserable.publish

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to do is to have an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which has a singleton `IEnumerator<T>`? Why not implement that explicitly, instead of using undocumented (?) behaviour of `List<T>`'s iterator?

Simply create a class that consumes a `IEnumerable<T>`, takes its iterator and wraps it in an implementation of `IEnumerator<T>` that has a dysfunctional `Reset` method. `IEnumerator<T>.GetEnumerator()` can then return the instance to that same iterator instead of creating a new one for each call. It could look something like this:

```
  public class OnlyOnceIterator<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T> {
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
    internal OnlyOnceIterator(IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
      enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public T Current => enumerator.Current;

    object IEnumerator.Current => enumerator.Current;

    public void Dispose() {
      enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => this;

    public bool MoveNext() {
      return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset() {
      return;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this;
  }
```

This could then be used in an extension method:

```
  public static OnlyOnceIterator<T> ToOnlyOnceIterator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
    if (sequence == null) {
      throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequence));
    }

    return new OnlyOnceIterator<T>(sequence);
  }
```

Additionally, I would prefer a more specific return type than `IEnumerable<T>`, since the returned behaviour is significantly different to what any user might expect from `IEnumerable<T>`. Consider creating a new interface that inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` with a more descriptive name. Through inheritance, Linq will still be able to be used, and you can create methods that only accept this specific interface, (compare this to `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: I bet it will not work with EF as you would dispose original decorated iterator on the very first run.

Comment: The points you make are all valid, but I also believe @DmitryNogin is right on this one.

Comment: @DmitryNogin You might be right, I have no experience with EF. Maybe changing the implementation of `OnlyOnceIterator.Dispose` to not dispose the enumerable (I overlooked that) might work. OTOH, in your answer you are eagerly evaluating your input sequence, so if you immediately consume that, that would mitigate the disposing risk as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would be the reasonable approach to implement it. Please note that `To` prefix in `ToIterable` documents full sequence materialization as framework design guideline naming conventions dictate - compare to `As` prefix.

It would be interesting to figure out how `AsIterable` could be done :)

```
public static class Iterable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToIterable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var array = source.ToArray();
        var i = 0;
        IEnumerable<T> once()
        {
            while (i < array.Length)
                yield return array[i++];
        }

        return once();
    }
}
```